# method not being called since adding parallax image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, methods, delegates

So i recently implemented parallax images into my app which works great, however this has broken a button which calls a method.

Here is a picture of my storyboard:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKvY9.jpg

Here is my .h code:

```
@interface _01FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIAccelerometerDelegate>{

UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;
float xoof;
float yoff;
float xvelocity;
float yvelocity;
float xaccel;
float yaccel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *BGScrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Track;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *trackingNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *posts;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *TrackPoint;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *Path;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *documentFolder;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *filePath;

-(void)parseTrackNo;
-(void)reloadTrackingNumber;
```

Here is the relevant parts of the .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
_BGScrollView.contentSize =      CGSizeMake(_BGScrollView.frame.size.width+30,_BGScrollView.frame.size.width+30);
self.accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
self.accelerometer.updateInterval = 0.03;
self.accelerometer.delegate = self;

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:-1 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil   repeats:YES];
}

-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{
float xx = -acceleration.x;
float yy = (acceleration.y + 0.5f) *2.0f;
float acceldirX;
if (xvelocity * -1.0f >0){
    acceldirX = 1.0;
}
else {
    acceldirX = -1.0;
}


float newdirX;
if (xx > 0){
    newdirX = 1.0;
}
else {
    newdirX = -1.0;
}

float acceldirY;
if (yvelocity * -1.0f >0){
    acceldirY = 1.0;
}
else {
    acceldirY = -1.0;
}

float newDirY;
if (yy > 0){
    newDirY = 1.0;
}
else {
    newDirY = -1.0;
}

if (acceldirX == newdirX) xoof = acceleration.x * 30;
if (acceldirY == newDirY) yoff = acceleration.y *30;
}
```

This is the button that has stopped calling the method:

```
- (IBAction)Track:(id)sender {
[self parseTrackNo]; //Not calling method
NSLog(@"Button Pressed"); //This gets logged correctly

}
```

I have tried removing all code changes so i suspect it is something to do with the button being nested inside the view in the storyboard or the delegate changes.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

EDIT as requested the code for parseTrackingNo (note this was working perfectly until the parallax changes):

```
-(void)parseTrackNo
{

    _01AppDelegate *appDelegate = (_01AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //Get Tracking Number from textField
    appDelegate.TrackingNumber = _trackingNumber.text;

    //Check String isn't empty
    if ([_trackingNumber.text  isEqual: @""]){

    } else{

        //Check against Royal Mail API
        NSString *trackingURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",   @"http://api.e44.co/tracktrace/", appDelegate.TrackingNumber];

        NSURL *royalMail = [NSURL URLWithString:trackingURL];

        //Return results
        NSData *royalMailResults = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:royalMail];

        //Parse JSON results
        if(royalMailResults != nil)
        {
            NSError *error = nil;
            id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:royalMailResults options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            if (error == nil)

            //Convert to dictionary/array
            self.posts = (NSDictionary *)result;
            NSArray *trackRecords = _posts[@"trackRecords"];

            //Return keys from posts (Dict)
            NSString *response = [self.posts valueForKeyPath:@"response"];
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);

            NSString *returnedTrackingNumber = [self.posts valueForKeyPath:@"trackingNumber"];
            NSLog(@"Returned tracking number: %@", returnedTrackingNumber);

            NSString *delivered = [self.posts valueForKeyPath:@"delivered"];
            NSLog(@"delivered: %@", delivered);

            NSString *signature = [self.posts valueForKeyPath:@"signature"];
            NSLog(@"Signature: %@", signature);


            //Track Records
            NSString *Date = [trackRecords valueForKeyPath:@"date"];
            NSLog(@"date: %@", Date);

            NSString *Time = [trackRecords valueForKeyPath:@"time"];
            NSLog(@"time: %@", Time);

            NSString *Status = [trackRecords valueForKeyPath:@"status"];
            NSLog(@"status: %@", Status);

            appDelegate.LocationData = [[trackRecords valueForKey:@"trackPoint"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            NSLog(@"GeoLocation: %@", appDelegate.LocationData);


            //Check for Errors returned
            if ([self.posts objectForKey:@"errorMsg"]) {
                NSLog(@"ERROR MOTHERFUCKER");
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]

                initWithTitle:@"Error"
                message:@"It appears that you have entered an incorrect tracking number"
                delegate:self
                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addPackageSegue" sender:self];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your `parseTrackNo` function?

Comment: Added the ParseTrackNo function :)

Comment: Thanks. Have you put an `NSLog` on the first line of the `parseTrackNo` function? If not, how did you determine that function is no longer being called? Also, have you tried removing parallax to make sure that's the source?

Comment: np. None of the NSLogs, for example: `NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);` is not being called. I have removed all the code changes with no improvement however i think the problem has something to do with nesting the button in the storyboard

Comment: All your logs are in the `else` statement, so if `[_trackingNumber.text  isEqual: @""]` is `TRUE`, none of your logs will output. Try putting a log before that line.

Comment: Damn! I am so stupid! I changed the text box and forgot to link it back up so _trackingNumber.text always equaled "" Which was causing the code not to execute! I really appreciate your help! I think i should get some sleep!

Comment: Haha I'm with you there. Lack of sleep = stupid mistakes ;) If you can upvote whichever comment helped you solve your problem that'd be great. Glad I could help.

Comment: I don't have enough rep at the moment to upvote comment - I promise I will upvote you when i have enough rep. For now have an internet high five and know that I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Haha fair enough. I appreciate the high five!